# CMake - Library with example subdirectory running as separate project

Tags: c++, cmake

**Edit 2 - Fixed!**

The issue was fixed by correctly using **absolute paths** rather than relative paths, and by adding `add_subdirectory` to `example/CMakelists.txt`.

I have updated the provided code (and will leave the repository in case somebody wants to use it as a starting point.

**Edit:**

- Adjusted `CMakelists.txt` files to use absolute paths only (as per recommendation from @Tsyvarev
- Added exact compilation error message

**Original post:**

I am trying to write a library, that contains example project, and can be added as a Git submodule. The desired structure would be this:

```
- source
  - MyLib
    lib.cpp
  - CMakelists.txt
- include
  - MyLib
    lib.h
- example
  main.cpp
  CMakelists.txt
CMakelists.txt (main CMake for library)
```

**What am I trying to achieve:**

- The structure should probably more or less stay, so one can install the library just by adding a gitmodule
- The `example` project should be capable of running on its own by loading the `CMakelists.txt` in the directory, and should be able to use the library

**What is my problem:**
My biggest problem is linking the example to the library which lives in a sibling folder, and make sure it compiles. I managed to write a CMakelists.txt in a way that my IDE understands `#include` statements correctly, but during compilation the function definitions are not found.
Could anyone provide some pointers, please?

**Exact compilation error message:**

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lMY_LIB
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MY_LIB_EXAMPLE.dir\build.make:95: MY_LIB_EXAMPLE.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/MY_LIB_EXAMPLE.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/MY_LIB_EXAMPLE.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: MY_LIB_EXAMPLE] Error 2
```

**CMakelists.txt files**
**CMakelists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
project(MY_LIB)
add_subdirectory(source)
```

**source/CMakelists.txt**

```
add_library(MY_LIB MyLib/library.cpp ../include/MyLib/library.h)

target_include_directories(MY_LIB PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyLib)
target_include_directories(MY_LIB PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/MyLib)
```

**example/CMakelists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get solution root
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR PARENT_PATH LIB_PATH)
cmake_path(SET LIB_INCLUDE_PATH "${LIB_PATH}/include")

message(${LIB_PATH})
message(${LIB_INCLUDE_PATH})

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set project name
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
project(MY_LIB_EXAMPLE)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add source
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
add_executable(MY_LIB_EXAMPLE main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(${LIB_PATH} library-build)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link libraries
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
target_link_libraries(MY_LIB_EXAMPLE MY_LIB)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link include directories
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
target_include_directories(MY_LIB_EXAMPLE PUBLIC ${LIB_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

**I created a sample repository with my setup**: https://github.com/jiriKralovec/cmake-library

Comment: It is a rule of Stack Overflow that **code** should be in the **question post**, not linked. Please, add relevant part of your code to the question post. BTW, `target_include_directories` should be called with **absolute directories**, passing `../include/MyLib` is not good. (Relative path is usable only as a part of `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>`.)

Comment: I added the code directly.

Comment: Oh, does that "but during compilation the function definitions are not found." means that you got "undefined reference" error? Please, add to the question post the **exact error message** too.

Comment: Fixed! I will add solution to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> he example project should be capable of running on its own by loading the CMakelists.txt in the directory, and should be able to use the library

Just add:

```
add_subdirectory(./../ some_unique_name_here)
```

I think I would remove `source/CMakelists.txt` and write it all in root `CMakelists.txt`. It's odd to use `../` to refer to include directories.

---

I suggest doing options and/or unit tests:

root CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(CTest)
add_library(MY_LIB ....)

# one design
if (BUILD_TESTING)
   add_subdirectory(example)
endif()

# another design
add_subdirectory(utilities)
```

example/CMakeLists.txt:

```
# if it is something simple, add unit test:
add_executable(MY_LIB_EXAMPLE1 <maybe EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL?> ...)
add_test(NAME MY_LIB_EXAMPLE1 COMMAND MY_LIB_EXAMPLE1)
```

utilities/CMakeLists.txt:

```
# if it is a utility, optionally build it
add_executable(MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH ...)
option(... BUILD_MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH OFF)
if(NOT BUILD_MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH)
   set_target_properties(
       MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH
       PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ON
   )
endif()
```

Either way, do one CMake build. Then if user wants to build the utility, he will do `cmake --build <builddir> --target MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH` (or `make MY_LIB_UTILITY_TO_DO_SMTH`). If *you* would want to build unit tests, you would do `cmake ... -D BUILD_TESTING=1`.

Some people add all unit tests executables as EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL and make special `add_custom_target(build_tests) add_target_dependencies(build_tests  MY_LIB_EXAMPLE1 etc. etc.)` and build that custom target before testing.

Comment: This, together with correctly using absolute paths, fixed the issue.
Thank you ever so much!